# Can not Find Module

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have made a custom skill in amazon alexa and when testing the Node js code in AWS as LAMBDA Function , it is giving following error :

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
  ]
}
```

Here is the Code, which is connecting to the firebase and updating its content

```
const firebase = require('firebase');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;  //<---Important

    var config = {
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyBQJasmuj2yzlkuXFwJ5-wL2kt0UMQ2V18',
      authDomain: 'deftdev-a2416.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://deftdev-a2416.firebaseio.com',
      storageBucket: 'deftdev-a2416.appspot.com'
    };
    //firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    //const db = firebase.database();

    if(firebase.apps.length == 0) {   // <---Important!!! In lambda, it will cause double initialization.
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }

    firebase.database().ref('rooms/' +'HPOQhC9smxUxSGhM1XlBtweiNDE3/'+'roomdetails/01/1/appliance/0/'+).update({
        toggle:1
    });
};
```

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: yeah , Check for the name you have given to the nodeJs file , if it is Index.js , give the same in the AWS console while creating LAMBDA function. this will solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the name of your entry point file name if it is Index.js , then give the same name in the AWS Lambda function entry point . This will help

Answer (score 1):

For completeness when using things like serverless framework you can get a very similar error if you installed your node modules locally with a later version of node than AWS supports.

The solution is to make sure you use the same node/npm version as you are in Lambda when you do an npm i

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is because of the way zipping the files making the problem. Instead of zipping the root folder you have to select all files and zip it like below,

Please upload all files and folders including your node_modules folder if you have one,

[image]